# Kanai's cube - remove level requirement

Tags: diablo-iii

If I use Kanai's cube to remove the level requirement, can I give it to a friend or is it only usable by me?

Comment: It's probably account bound, but I did not check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't trade the item to another account, but you can stash it and use it with your other characters.